Computing inverse of sums of strictly monotanically function (e.g CDF of random variables)
I'm trying to compute the general case of inverse of CDF of $Y=X^2$, where $Y,X$ are random variables. Given that a CDF $F_X$ is a strictly increasing function, also has to be it's inverse. The CDF $F_{X^2}=F_Y$ also is stricly increasing a it's general formula is:
$$F_Y(y)=F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(-\sqrt{y})$$
What I tried it is to take the inverse of both sumands in the expresion above, and recombine them in a meaningful way, but it failed. Then, I thougth of taking the bigger sumand $F_X(\sqrt{x})$ and shifting to the right in a variable way, so of the form
$$F_Y^{-1}=\left(F_X^{-1}\left(y+g(y)\right)\right)^2$$
where $g(y)$ should be a monotonic function in the interval $[0,1]$. After try and error, I came with the function:
$$ F_Y^{-1}(y)=\left(F_X^{-1}\left(y+{1\over2}(1-y)\right)\right)^2$$
At least visually, match the graph of the inverse CDF, but if it is correct, I don't understand the "why" should be it.

Given that $-F_X(-\sqrt{x})=F_X(\sqrt{x})-1$ for a symmetric CDF $F_X$, the CDF of $Y$ can be rewrite as $2F_X(\sqrt{x})-1$ and then the rest follow easily.
In the general case, $\Bbb P(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq\sqrt{y})$ as $\Bbb P(X\leq\sqrt{y})+\Bbb P(X\leq-\sqrt{y})-1$, or in terms of $F_X$:
$$F_{X^2}(y)=F_X(\sqrt{y})+F_X(-\sqrt{y})-1$$

Doesn't that assume symmetry? I'm not sure if you are going to get a general formula outside of that case (or other shape assumptions). What's the context of your question?

@GuillaumeDehaene you are absolutly right
